# Load next image once previous has finished

Tags: javascript, css, image

I am trying to work out how to load a image into a button but wait for the previous image to download before it downloads the next image.

I don't want to use jQuery for this.

I am currently loading the images to the buttons like the following:

```
<button onclick="icon1();"><img src="icon1.png"/></button>
<button onclick="icon2();"><img src="icon2.png"/></button>
<button onclick="icon3();"><img src="icon3.png"/></button>
<button onclick="icon4();"><img src="icon4.png"/></button>
<button onclick="icon5();"><img src="icon5.png"/></button>
<button onclick="icon6();"><img src="icon6.png"/></button>
<button onclick="icon7();"><img src="icon7.png"/></button>
<button onclick="icon8();"><img src="icon8.png"/></button>
```

How can I make it so that it downloads icon1.png first, then once it's finished loading that image then download icon2.png then once that is done download icon3.png download the next etc. rather than download them all at the same time when the page opens.

I have seen examples online, but it only shows jQuery which is what I don't want to use.

I was thinking of loading the image using CSS (background: url(icon1.png) no-repeat;)

But not sure if that is going to help me. Sounds like to me it's just another way to load the image when the button is created.

Anyone able to help me load the image only when the previous image has finished loading ?

Comment: May I ask why you are against jQuery?

Comment: If you do this in css you won't have any control, the browsers rendering engine will decide.  You'd have to use javascript.

Comment: @Math Nerd Productions I am loading this onto a product and the jQuery file is too big to load onto it so I need to somehow work without jQuery. I would like to use jQuery but I am limited.

Answer (score 0):

```
var imgSources = ['icon1.png', 'icon2.png', 'icon3.png'];
function loadNext(index){
    var tempImg = new Image();
    tempImg.onload = function() {
        /*Assuming You have experience in Javascript Dom manipulation*/
        //Assign the image to Dom.
        //img1.src = this.src;

        if(++index < imgSources.length)loadNext(index);
    }
    tempImg.src =  imgSources[index];
}
loadNext(0);
```